# Parsing XML with close shortcut

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing

I seem to have an issue with the XML I am trying to parse.

The XML looks like this:

```
<room>
    <property1>3</property1>
    <property2>2</property2>
    ...
    <instances>
        <instance name="instance1" x="0" y="0" />
        <instance name="instance2" x="0" y="0" />
    <instances>
</room>
```

I'm trying to iterate through all of the `instance` tags, however C# doesn't seem to support tags with the close shortcut (`<tag attribute="value" />`).

Here is my code:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml");

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "instances")
    {
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            Logger.Log(reader.Name);    
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to only iterate over one `instance` tag and skip the rest. I've tried a few methods including LINQ and XDocument, but it seems to have the same effect. I then realized that it might be, because C# doesn't support the tag closing shortcuts. Is this true? Is there a way I can enable support for the close shortcuts? Am I doing something incorrectly?

If C# does not support the closing shortcuts, is there a good C# XML library I can use that supports this?

Comment: It should, but your instances is not closed correctly? </instances>

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: FYI, C# has no XML support at all. The support is all part of the .NET Framework, not part of the programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would avoid using `XmlReader` unless you really have to - typically because the document is huge. If you're parsing a document that you're happy to have in memory the whole time, you can just use LINQ to XML (`XDocument.Load` etc) which will be much simpler.

Within `XmlReader`, you can use [`IsEmptyElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.isemptyelement.aspx) to detect that you're on such an element, and avoid calling `Read` again.

Here's an example of using LINQ to XML to read all the `instance` elements instead:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
foreach (var instance in doc.Descendants("instance"))
{
    Logger.Log(instance.Attribute("name").Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `do-while loop` would be more suitable:

```
 do {
     reader.Read();
     Logger.Log(reader.Name);
 }
 while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement);
```